# Subclassing QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have system that has classes derived from QGraphicsWidget. I manage derived class objects in layouts on QGraphicsScene. Now I need a compound item that contain two or more QGraphicsWidget in it and also I need to put that item inside my layout. So I choose QGraphicsItemGroup and write I class like this.

```
class CompositeItem : public QGraphicsItemGroup,public QGraphicsLayoutItem
{   
   ...  
};
```

I only implemented sizeHint function again.
When add CompositeItem instance to layout it does not shown.
What may cause this? Where I made wrong?

Comment: Did you actually add your widgets with `addToGroup`?

Comment: For clearance, here is my CompositeItem constructor implementation
    CompositeItem::CompositeItem(QString itemId,  QList<QGraphicsWidget *> children)
{
    QGraphicsWidget *child;
    foreach(child,children)
    {
       addToGroup(child);
    }
}

Comment: In the Qt documentation, it is specified that QGraphicsLayoutItem
is an abstract class and that you should re-implements several methods (the sinzeHint() you already redefined but also the public method setGeometry()). Did you implements those methods?

Comment: I do not implement setGeometry(). I will give it a try.

Comment: I implemented setGeometry. Still it does not shown.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is related with QGraphicsLayoutItem base class.

Comment: Did you try with an actual implementation of a QGraphicsLayoutItem class like QGraphicsLayoutGrid?

Comment: I mean to try :
class CompositeItem : public QGraphicsItemGroup, public QGraphicsLayoutGrid.

Comment: QGraphicsGridLayout does not suitable for my application.

Comment: Although it is not suitable for my application I try QGraphicsGridLayout. My objects are shown this time.

Answer (score 0):

Call show() on either the QGraphicsItemGroup or QGraphicsWidgets after adding to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add setGraphicsItem( this ) to your constructor.